# angular-bootstrap-calendar not loading first time

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-bootstrap

I am trying to load the demo the first time locally, it loads correctly with no errors except of the calendar not showing. All the buttons for today. month. day, year and even the "edit events" section is showing properly.

I am using windows, running on tomcat 7. I also included angular, moment, ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-css and ui-bootstrap.

Any hint is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Post the code, there might be an exception blocking the display

Comment: there is really no errors on the browser log, it is a local copy on localhost of https://mattlewis.me/angular-bootstrap-calendar/